# is it possible for two rows of a column (primary key) of the table to have same character/value with same foreign key(another column)

Tags: sql-server

is it possible for two rows of a column (primary key) of the table to have same character/value with same foreign key(another column)?

Reference Image

[image]

Comment: the primary key always will have unique value but a foreign key can have duplicate values unless the unique constraint is not created on it.

Comment: As char/value column in primary key so it is not possible to have same values like aaa in more than two rows.

Comment: The `primary key` is unique by definition. `Foreign Key` values must be in the domain of a mater table's `primary key` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the ***primary key is, it must contain a unique value for each row of data***, so its not possible. If you try to put same PK It will throw error something like

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_table'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table. The duplicate key value is (aaa).